# Manisfest for Administrator access prompt

Tags: c#, admin, manifest

I have a small help project. Right now, I run the .exe of that project(ABC.exe) by right-clicking the mouse and then specifying 'Run as an Administrator'.

But, I need to have a manifest where in I just have to double click the .exe file and Windows will prompt me to ask whether it should proceed with Administrator privileges or not. (Yes/No/Cancel messagebox)

I have added a manifest file(ABC.exe.manifest) into the project with this code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <!-- UAC Manifest Options
            If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
            requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

            Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
            If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
            compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
        -->
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

***I have two questions -***

1. Is this the right way to achieve my objective?
2. If yes, can someone shed some light on how exactly this works? I am afraid I have only exposure know-how information of manifest and not in depth-knowledge exactly as specific for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to do this in .net.
One tip I have: make sure you added the manifest to the project by right clicking the project and adding new item, then selecting manifest. If you copy manifest from another project, you need to clean and rebuild for the change to have effect.

Comment: No I have added the manifest file by right clicking the project and adding new item, then selecting manifest.